# PHP nested Json from array

Tags: php, json, loops

i need to create a json from an array of values like this:

```
[items_list] => Array
    (
        [0] => FattureInCloud\Model\ReceivedDocumentItemsListItem Object
            (
                [openAPINullablesSetToNull:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => product_id
                    )

                [container:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 317193954
                        [product_id] => 
                        [code] => 
                        [name] => Gestione pratica
                        [measure] => 
                        [net_price] => 0.6
                        [category] => 
                        [qty] => 1
                        [vat] => Fatture\Model\VatType Object
                            (
                                [container:protected] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2531827
                                        [value] => 22
                                        [description] => 22%-GENERICO
                                        [notes] => 
                                        [e_invoice] => 
                                        [ei_type] => 
                                        [ei_description] => 
                                        [editable] => 
                                        [is_disabled] => 
                                    )

                            )

                        [stock] => 0
                    )

            )
    )
```

i need to get a json that looks like this:

```
"lines": [
{
"desc": "Some additional text",
"qty": "10",
"subprice": 100,
"tva_tx": "20.000",
"fk_product": "1",
"remise_percent": "0",
"date_start": 1494252128,
"date_end": 1494194400,
"info_bits": "0"
}
],
```

I tried to use a foreach loop but to no avail, it just returns the values ​​from the last data set
this is my cycle:

```
foreach($result['items_list'] as $item) {
    $myObj->lines = new stdClass;
    $myObj->lines->desc =  $item['name'];
    $myObj->lines->qty = $item['qty'];
    $myObj->lines->subprice = $item['net_price'];
}
```

is anyone able to give me a hand? any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$myObj->lines` should be an array, not a single object. The loop should push a nested associative array onto this array.

```
$myObj->lines = [];
foreach($result['items_list'] as $item) {
    $myObj->lines[] = [
        'desc' =>  $item['name'],
        'qty' => $item['qty'],
        'subprice' => $item['net_price'],
        ...
    ];
}
```

Or use `array_map()`:

```
$myObj->lines = array_map(function($item) {
    return [
        'desc' =>  $item['name'],
        'qty' => $item['qty'],
        'subprice' => $item['net_price'],
        ...
    ];
}, $result['items_list']);
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
$finaArr= []:
foreach($result['items_list'] as $item) {
   $tmp=array("qty"=>$item["qty"],
       "subprice"=> $item["price"],
       "tva_tx"=>$item["tax"], 
       "fk_product"=>$item["name"], 
       "remise_percent"=>$item["remise"],
       "date_start"=>$item["startDate"], 
       "date_end"=>$item["endDate"], 
       "info_bits"=>$item["info"]
        );
  array_push($finaArr,$tmp):
}
$myObj->lines = $finaArr;
```